# unable to use default programs in elicpse w/android. (tabs + swipe)

Tags: eclipse

I am new to android, so I may be having a dumb moment.
I don't think so since all over the internet everyone else gets it fine.
I am trying to get the default `tabs + swipe` navigation in eclipse with android to work.
I am creating an android app that will need to utilize tabs, and I thought that naturally people would expect to be able to swipe.

I have never been able to get the default package that eclipse loads to work.
Even after following what others have already done across multiple sites.
To add insult to injury I can almost never get the graphical gui to show up in eclipse (on any program, not just the `tab + swipe`).

I have figured out that you have to select the `theme` dropdown menu and that works for apparently everyone.
However for me it does not.
I can sit there and select the screen size then the orientation back and forth for like a minute and then magically there it is!
If I leave that screen to go edit a `.java` file or any file when I come back the gui is lost again!
It is almost unusable.
I have tried reinstalling.
I followed all instructions to the `T` when installing eclipse and android adt.

I have windows 7 64bit with eclipse classic. Current versions of all software as of yesterday (25th).

Has anyone else had this problem?

Thanks.